# C# XML complex query to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a complex collection from a 'select new' statement . I have been trying to output it to a new 'XDocument' but I am unable to. Thank you for any assistance with this.

Source sample:

```
<GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
  <GetAssetWarrantyResult>
    <Faults />
    <Response>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>UI002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>OPTI 3020,TIGRISSFFFBTX</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>584290163</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>1CZTF02</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>422-0052</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>984-0092</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2017-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>939-7358</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2015-03-22T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2015-03-21T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>939-6868</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>421-9982</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>525-0013</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2022-03-24T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>422-0008</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>D</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
      <DellAsset>
        <AssetParts nil="true" />
        <CountryLookupCode>11</CountryLookupCode>
        <CustomerNumber>100540040</CustomerNumber>
        <IsDuplicate>false</IsDuplicate>
        <ItemClassCode>7M002</ItemClassCode>
        <LocalChannel>05</LocalChannel>
        <MachineDescription>POWEREDGE R720XD, ORCA S PE</MachineDescription>
        <OrderNumber>339791846</OrderNumber>
        <ParentServiceTag nil="true" />
        <ServiceTag>1VF0TW1</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Warranties>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>936-7263</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>SV</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Silver Premium Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>8</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>983-6402</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>KK</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>11</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>DELL</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2016-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>936-7243</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
          <Warranty>
            <EndDate>2014-03-20T23:59:59</EndDate>
            <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
            <ItemNumber>989-2701</ItemNumber>
            <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
            <ServiceLevelDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceLevelDescription>
            <ServiceLevelGroup>5</ServiceLevelGroup>
            <ServiceProvider>UNY</ServiceProvider>
            <StartDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</StartDate>
          </Warranty>
        </Warranties>
      </DellAsset>
      </Response>
    </GetAssetWarrantyResult>
</GetAssetWarrantyResponse>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var xlQueryTest = (from mainRequest in testing.Descendants("Response")
                  select new
                  {
                      Baseinfo = (from baseInfo in mainRequest.Descendants("DellAsset")
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      MachineName = baseInfo.Element("MachineDescription").Value,
                                      ServiceTag = baseInfo.Element("ServiceTag").Value,
                                      WarrantyStart = baseInfo.Element("ShipDate").Value,
                                      Warranties = (from warranty in baseInfo.Descendants("Warranties")
                                                    select new
                                                    {
                                                        Service = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceLevelDescription").Value,
                                                        Provider = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceProvider").Value,
                                                        StartDate = (string)warranty.Element("StartDate").Value,
                                                        EndDate = (string)warranty.Element("EndDate").Value,
                                                        TypeOfWarranty = (string)warranty.Element("EntitlementType").Value
                                                    }).GroupBy(x => x.Service)
                                  }).AsEnumerable().ToList()
                  });

var newDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Request",
    xlQueryTest.Select(a => a.Baseinfo).Select( 
        //HOWTO
        //iterate through "BaseInfo" Elements
        //iterate through "Warranties" Collection
```

I am having difficulties accessing the collections

My result I am trying to achieve would be:

```
<Request>
    <BaseInfo>
        <MachineName>a</MachineName>
        <ServiceTag>a12345</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>01/01/2000</ShipDate>
            <Warranties>
                <Warranty>
                    <ServiceLevelDescription>dfdlkfj</ServiceLevelDescription>
                    <ServiceProvider>ABC</ServiceProvider>
                    <StartDate>01/01/2001</StartDate>
                    <EndDate>01/05/2007</EndDate>
                </Warranty>
                <Warranty>
                </Warranty>
            </Warranties>
    </BaseInfo>
    <BaseInfo>
        <MachineName>b</MachineName>
        <ServiceTag>b12345</ServiceTag>
        <ShipDate>01/01/2010</ShipDate>
            <Warranties>
                <Warranty>
                    <ServiceLevelDescription>dfdlkfj</ServiceLevelDescription>
                    <ServiceProvider>ABCF</ServiceProvider>
                    <StartDate>01/01/2011</StartDate>
                    <EndDate>01/05/2017</EndDate>
                </Warranty>
                <Warranty>
                </Warranty>
            </Warranties>
    </BaseInfo>
</Request>
```

**Update:** I put this together to try and explain further what I am trying to do.

How can I translate this into a 'new XDocument' in order to get the desired result (above)

```
foreach(var request in xlQueryTest)
            {
                //<Request>

                foreach(var machine in request.Baseinfo)
                {
                    //<BaseInfo>
                        //<MachineName>machine.MachineName</MachineName>
                        //<ServiceTag>machine.ServiceTag</ServiceTag>
                        //<ShipDate>machine.WarrantyStart</ShipDate>
                        //  <Warranites>
                        foreach(var warranty in machine.Warranties)
                        {
                            //<Warranty>
                                //<ServiceLevelDescription>warranty.Service</ServiceLevelDescription>
                                //<ServiceProvider>warranty.Provier</ServiceProvider>
                                //<StartDate>warranty.StartDate</StartDate>
                                //<EndDate>warranty.EndDate</EndDate>
                            //</Warranty>
                        }
                        //  </Warranties>
                    }
                    //</BaseInfo>
                }
                //</Request>
            }
```

**Answer:**
I went with har07's answer because it addresses the duplicate issue. Jdweng's solution is elegant but does not correct the duplicate information.

```
var xlQueryTest = (from mainRequest in testing.Descendants("Response")
                               select new
                               {
                                   Baseinfo = (from baseInfo in mainRequest.Descendants("DellAsset")
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   MachineName = baseInfo.Element("MachineDescription").Value,
                                                   ServiceTag = baseInfo.Element("ServiceTag").Value,
                                                   WarrantyStart = baseInfo.Element("ShipDate").Value,
                                                   Warranties = (from warranty in baseInfo.Descendants("Warranty")
                                                                 select new
                                                                 {
                                                                     Service = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceLevelDescription"),
                                                                     Provider = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceProvider"),
                                                                     StartDate = (string)warranty.Element("StartDate"),
                                                                     EndDate = (string)warranty.Element("EndDate"),
                                                                     TypeOfWarranty = (string)warranty.Element("EntitlementType")
                                                                 }).GroupBy(x => x.Service)
                                               }).AsEnumerable().ToList()
                               });
                        var newDocument =
                            new XDocument(new XElement("Request",
                            from t in xlQueryTest
                            from q in t.Baseinfo
                            select
                            new XElement("BaseInfo",
                                new XElement("MachineDescription", q.MachineName),
                                new XElement("ServiceTag", q.ServiceTag),
                                new XElement("ShipDate", q.WarrantyStart),
                                new XElement("Warranites",
                                from g in q.Warranties
                                select
                                    new XElement("Warranty",
                                    new XElement("ServiceLevelDescription", g.Key),
                                    new XElement("ServiceProvider", g.First().Provider),
                                    new XElement("StartDate", g.First().StartDate),
                                    new XElement("EndDate", g.First().EndDate)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ));
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: _Thank you for any assistance with this._ Seriously can't assist you without knowing the ABC of your XML.

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry, Added sample of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Add a ToList() at end of query so you can hover over results and easily view results.

Comment: You closing request is missing an 'e'.  Your tags in xml don't match the query.

Comment: @jdweng, VS2015 - you can debug lambda's result without `.ToList()`

Comment: What I am trying to do it take 'xlQueryTest' and create an XDocument from it. The XML is to give an idea of the structure of the XDocument that would be created. This issue I am having is accessing the information within 'xlQueryTest' when passing it to 'var newDocument'

Comment: But the query isn't returning anything with the xml you posted.  You need to post the input and output xml.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, added the source above.

Comment: Fabio : I is much easier to hover over variable (or add to watch) when the object is a list and see values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want grouped warranties from `Baseinfo.Warranties` to be just expanded in the output XML, this is one possible way :

```
var newDocument =
        new XDocument(new XElement("Request",
            from query in xlQueryTest
            from baseInfo in query.Baseinfo
            select
            new XElement("BaseInfo",
                new XElement("MachineDescription", baseInfo.MachineName),
                new XElement("ServiceTag", baseInfo.ServiceTag),
                new XElement("ShipDate", baseInfo.WarrantyStart),
                new XElement("Warranites",
                    from grp in baseInfo.Warranties
                    from warranty in grp
                    select
                    new XElement("Warranty",
                        new XElement("ServiceLevelDescription", warranty.Service),
                        new XElement("ServiceProvider", warranty.Provider),
                        new XElement("StartDate", warranty.StartDate),
                        new XElement("EndDate", warranty.EndDate)
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AH1j07)</kbd>**

If you want the grouped items to be outputted as one element instead, for example displaying values only from the first item of current group, modify creation of `<Warranites>` element part to be something like the following :

```
new XElement("Warranites",
    from g in q.Warranties
    select
    new XElement("Warranty",
        new XElement("ServiceLevelDescription", g.Key),
        new XElement("ServiceProvider", g.First().Provider),
        new XElement("StartDate", g.First().StartDate),
        new XElement("EndDate", g.First().EndDate)
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you actually test this code and compare with posted xml?

Comment: We the demo webpage has a lot more code than you posted.  Why go from xml to strings and back to strings when you can simply take old elements and add to new document.  My code is a lot simplier.

Comment: That's a cool solution, very tight.  But why not just use XSL for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication77
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
            "<Request>" +
            "</Request>";

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement request = newDoc.Descendants("Request").FirstOrDefault();

            XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement dellAsset in oldDoc.Descendants("DellAsset"))
            {
                XElement baseInfo = new XElement("BaseInfo");
                request.Add(baseInfo);

                baseInfo.Add(dellAsset.Element("MachineDescription"));
                baseInfo.Add(dellAsset.Element("ParentServiceTag"));
                baseInfo.Add(dellAsset.Element("ShipDate"));

                XElement warranties = new XElement("Warranties");
                baseInfo.Add(warranties);
                XElement latestWarranty = dellAsset.Descendants("Warranty")
                    .OrderBy(x => (DateTime)x.Element("EndDate")).LastOrDefault();

                warranties.Add( new XElement("Warranty", new XElement[] {
                              latestWarranty.Element("ServiceLevelDescription"),
                              latestWarranty.Element("ServiceProvider"),
                              latestWarranty.Element("StartDate"),
                              latestWarranty.Element("EndDate"),
                              latestWarranty.Element("EntitlementType")
                }));

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Per OP's question: "**I have been trying to output it to a new 'XDocument' but I am unable to.**".  Not seeing a new `XDocument` in your answer....

Comment: BaseInfo is not XML, it is a collection of strings.  Not sure what you are trying to do with original xml data.  You can use the write method to save the variable testing to a file.

Comment: @jdweng I apologize for my ignorance in this. The whole reason I am approaching it this way is the source information is not formatted the correct way. Ex: Unneeded information, duplicate information. I would like to clean it up prior to working with it.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for the response. This cleans up the XML very nicely. The issue I have is the warranties still have duplicate information. If you could group by the "ServiceLevelDescription" to try and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: What duplicates.  You really want the latest so use Linq to get the latest.  Very simple modification.  See changes.